# Liaison dans « d'autres chats à fouetter »

Tags: registre-familier, liaisons

Dans l'expression *avoir d'autres chats à fouetter*, la liaison entre *chats* et *à* est-elle facultative ou bien interdite ?

Je veux dire facultative après un nom au pluriel, mais puisque l'expression elle-même est familière, faire une telle liaison semble un peu bizarre. Qu'en pensez-vous ?

Answer (score 3):

En langage familier la liaison ne se fait pas, l'oralité ne restitue pas l'orthographe dans ce cas,

- peut-être parce que la dernière lettre de *chat* au singulier est une consonne, et que le pluriel est phonétiquement invariable (il se prononce de la même façon),
- peut-être parce que cela ferait bizarre *des chat-z-a fouetter*, alors que l'on mange "des-z-haricots" : le *h* est muet comme le *t* de chat, mais il commence la phrase, de plus *des* est un mot pluriel,
- peut-être que cette bizarrerie, l'ajout inconscient du *-z-* pour prononcer le *s* muet change les phonèmes et la prosodie.
  On passe de "ch[***a***]t(s) ***à***" à de "ch[***a***]t(s)-***z***-***à***" : au lieu d'avoir une voyelle allongée par jonction des deux *a* à prononcer (avec une diminution d'intensité au milieu, rarement un silence complet), on en prononce deux.

Pourtant certains lettrés font la liaison, comme ils s'appliquent à faire toutes les liaisons, comme ils s'évertuent à utiliser le subjonctif au passé, devenu rare à l'oral de nos jours.

Comment: Le subjonctif devenu rare??

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez - C'est vrai, j'exagère un peu car je pensais surtout à l'imparfait et au plus-que-parfait. J'ai amendé ma réponse.